# What is Optimality in Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I know the definition: - 
An optimal policy (pi)* satisfies (pi)* >= (pi) for all (pi)
An optimal policy is guaranteed to exist, but may not be unique.
What do these two lines mean?

Comment: Hi @Naman Jain and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please consider accepting the response in case it was useful to you (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), otherwise, you can add a comment to obtain some extra details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an agent whose goal is to gain score in a video game. Here as the agent learns to play the game we assign a score to its policy (e.g. the game score). The optimal policy would be the policy that results in the most score gained. For example there might be several ways to collect all the scores in the game, all of which are optimal policies.

Also, as I just mentioned, these policies are not unique, there might be infinite ways to maximize the score in some cases.

hope that helps.